# Solve equation with Log[s]

Tags: equation-solving

When i try to solve the following equation, i get error message that 
"Solve::dinv: ...."due to the presence of Log[s0] term. How to solve this? the code is given below:

```
sig = 2.;
ks = (Pi/6) (4 sig/Log[s0])^3;
i0 = (2/(9 Pi))^(1/3) sig^0.5 s0^(2 - 0.5 ks);
n0 = i0 tc
m0 = (i0 ks^(1/3) + ((s0 - 1) n0/3)) tc
a0 = (i0 ks^(2/3) + (2 (s0 - 1) m0/3)) tc
rr = 100.;
tc = 1000.;
Solve[{rr - (s0/tc) - i0 ks - (s0 - 1) tc (
  i0 ks^(2/3) +
   (
    2 (s0 - 1) tc/3 (i0 ks^(1/3) + (s0 - 1) tc i0/3)
    )
  ) == 0}, s0
]
```

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: This is a numerical problem, use `FindRoot`

Comment: Thank you george2079, it worked....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amplifying on answer by [yode](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/21532/yode). Use exact expressions to avoid need to [Rationalize](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) when using `Solve`

```
sig = 2;
ks = (Pi/6) (4 sig/Log[s0])^3;
i0 = (2/(9 Pi))^(1/3) Sqrt[sig] s0^(2 - ks/2);
n0 = i0 tc;
m0 = (i0 ks^(1/3) + ((s0 - 1) n0/3)) tc;
a0 = (i0 ks^(2/3) + (2 (s0 - 1) m0/3)) tc;
rr = 100;
tc = 1000;

f[s0_] = rr - (s0/tc) - 
   i0 ks - (s0 - 
      1) tc (i0 ks^(2/3) + (2 (s0 - 1) tc/
         3 (i0 ks^(1/3) + (s0 - 1) tc i0/3)));
```

Use a constraint with `Solve` or `NSolve`

```
Solve[{f[s0] == 0, 9 < s0 < 11}, s0][[1]] // N

(*  {s0 -> 10.0023}  *)

NSolve[{f[s0] == 0, 9 < s0 < 11}, s0][[1]]

(*  {s0 -> 10.0023}  *)

FindRoot[f[s0], {s0, 10}]

(*  {s0 -> 10.0023}  *)
```

Comment: Thank you for detail explanation...Bob Hanlon

Answer (score 2):

This equation isn't be solved by `Solve` usually.First we should use `Plot` to estimate its initial value.Then we use `FindRoot` to solve it.The process like following:

```
sig = 2.;
ks = (Pi/6) (4 sig/Log[s0])^3;
i0 = (2/(9 Pi))^(1/3) sig^0.5 s0^(2 - 0.5 ks);
n0 = i0 tc;
m0 = (i0 ks^(1/3) + ((s0 - 1) n0/3)) tc;
a0 = (i0 ks^(2/3) + (2 (s0 - 1) m0/3)) tc;
rr = 100.;
tc = 1000.;
Plot[rr - (s0/tc) - 
  i0 ks - (s0 - 
     1) tc (i0 ks^(2/3) + (2 (s0 - 1) tc/
        3 (i0 ks^(1/3) + (s0 - 1) tc i0/3))), {s0, -8, 8}]
```

[image]

Then you get it.

```
FindRoot[rr - (s0/tc) - 
  i0 ks - (s0 - 
     1) tc (i0 ks^(2/3) + (2 (s0 - 1) tc/
        3 (i0 ks^(1/3) + (s0 - 1) tc i0/3))), {s0, 7.}]
```

> {s0 -> 10.0023}

Comment: thank you yode, it (FindRoot) worked...